# Expression type '@lvalue CGPoint' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the length of a game by making an object move faster or slower through a variable on a segmented control but i get the error Expression type '@lvalue CGPoint' is ambiguous without more context.

```
@IBAction func control(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
//variable changes in order to change the distance "purple" moves
            var length: Int = 10;
        } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
            var length: Int = 20;
        } else{
            var length: Int = 30;
        }
    }


    @IBAction func Red(sender: AnyObject) {
        var l: Int;
        if self.Purple.center.y > self.TopFinish.center.y && self.Purple.center.y < 
        self.Finish.center.y && y==0{
            UIImageView.animate(withDuration:0.75, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, 
        animations: {
        //i got the error below:
                self.Purple.center.y += length;

                }, completion: nil)
        }
        if  self.Purple.center.y >= self.Finish.center.y{
            Label.text="Red Wins!"
            Restart.isHidden=false;
            self.Purple.center.y = self.Finish.center.y
        y=1
        }

    }
```

Comment: in you `control` function you are creating a local variable `length` and it looks like in your `Red` func you are trying to access a global variable also called `length`

Answer (score 0):

You never defined `lenght` in your `func Red`

You need to make a global variable or define it inside the function.